# ASP.NET core + Azure cambiar a entorno de despliegue

Tags: asp.net, azure, deployment

Como cambio el **entorno** a uno de despliegue.

Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que paso al final es:

1. El error era con la base de datos.
2. Al momento de usarla, esta no existía.
3. Allí me debía mostrar la pagina con el error, pero al ser un entorno
   de producción me da esta advertencia.

La solución fue corregir el error y ya no tuve el problema, no es la mejor opción pero me basta por ahora, lo que sigue es capturar los errores y mostrar una vista propia para decir cual fue el problema.

Si alguno tiene una idea de como llevar esto de mejor manera, soy todo oídos o en este caso ojos. Gracias.